# Can't use network printer via samba, how to debug the problem?

Tags: 14.04, printing, samba

I've got a network printer available through samba and I'd like to use it from my Ubuntu 14.04. Unfortunately simply adding it through Printers is not enough. If I try to use it it says: `Connection failed: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL` and then `Unable to connect to CIFS host, will retry in 60 seconds...`

How can I debug these things and learn the reason it doesn't work?

`/var/log/cups/error_log`

```
E [23/Jul/2014:13:58:41 +0200] [Job 5] Connection failed: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
E [23/Jul/2014:13:58:42 +0200] [Job 5] Connection failed: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
E [23/Jul/2014:13:58:43 +0200] [Job 5] Connection failed: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
E [23/Jul/2014:13:58:43 +0200] [Job 5] Unable to connect to CIFS host, will retry in 60 seconds...
E [23/Jul/2014:13:59:44 +0200] [Job 5] Connection failed: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
E [23/Jul/2014:13:59:45 +0200] [Job 5] Connection failed: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
E [23/Jul/2014:13:59:46 +0200] [Job 5] Connection failed: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
E [23/Jul/2014:13:59:46 +0200] [Job 5] Unable to connect to CIFS host, will retry in 60 seconds...
E [23/Jul/2014:14:00:47 +0200] [Job 5] Connection failed: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
E [23/Jul/2014:14:00:48 +0200] [Job 5] Connection failed: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
E [23/Jul/2014:14:00:49 +0200] [Job 5] Connection failed: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
E [23/Jul/2014:14:00:49 +0200] [Job 5] Unable to connect to CIFS host, will retry in 60 seconds...
```

Answer (score 8):

Maybe it will be helpful for someone.

I encountered the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04. Steps below solved it for me:

- remove printer added via `System Settings->Printers`
- open `localhost:631`
  in the browser
- go to Administration tab, click Add Printer button and follow the instructions

I don't know why, but only after adding printer in such way it works for me and for my colleagues.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by modifying the printer Device URI to include the username and password, in the format:

> ```
> smb://username:password@uri.com/printer
> ```

(to change this, go to System settings > Printers, then right-click on the printer icon)

Comment: Note that if you have to put a domain, you can enter it as follows: `smb://domain\username:password@...`